# Формирование std::tuple в C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые.

У меня следующий вопрос:

Пусть есть шаблонный класс вот такого вида:

```
template <class... Ts> class MyClass 
{ 
public:
      using TupleT = std::tuple<Ts...>;
      ...
private:
      TupleT m_tuple;         
};
```

и есть шаблонный класс

```
template <size_t I, class TupleT> WrapperT { ... };
```

Хочется сделать следующее: изменить тип m_tuple внутри MyClass с указанного выше на тип TupleWrappedT таким образом, что WrapperT будет выбирать по индексу элемент из TupleT и оборачивать его в себя.
Вопрос, собственно, в том, как такой тип определить. Я придумал только

```
template <size_t... Is> using TupleWrappedT = std::tuple<WrapperT<Is, TupleT>...>;
```

возможно ли обойтись без приставки `template <size_t... Is>`? С учетом того, что элементы Is должны быть последовательны в диапазоне от 0 до `sizeof...(Ts)`, а значит, известны на этапе компиляции.

Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Ваш код оборачивает все аргументы во WrapperT, но, судя по всему, Вы хотите обернуть только I-й? UPD: понял, WrapperT занимается перестановкой + оборачиванием.

Comment: Мой совет - посмотреть на библиотечные реализации функций над tuple'ами, там везде используется вспомогательная имплементация, работающая через index_sequence

Comment: Да, index_sequence я видел (правда он только в С++14, а у меня допустим только С++11, но я нашел реализацию). Просто не хватает мне дзен в шаблонах, чтобы уразуметь, куда его тут привинтить))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держите :)

```
#include <tuple>

template <size_t I, class TupleT> struct WrapperT {};

template <class Tuple, size_t... Is> 
static std::tuple<WrapperT<Is, Tuple>...> wrap_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>);

template <class Tuple>
static auto wrap() -> decltype(wrap_impl<Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>()));

template <class... Ts> class MyClass 
{ 
public:
      using TupleT = std::tuple<Ts...>;
      using TupleWrappedT = decltype(wrap<TupleT>());
private:
      TupleT m_tuple;         
};



int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<MyClass<int, float>::TupleT, std::tuple<int, float>>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<MyClass<int, float>::TupleWrappedT, std::tuple<WrapperT<0, std::tuple<int, float>>, WrapperT<1, std::tuple<int, float>>>>::value, "!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. То что надо!

Comment: Только ответственность за реализацию WrapperT берёте на себя Вы - там уже и из Tuple можно элемент достать, можно что угодно с ним сделать

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я чего-то не понял, но разве `std::tuple_element` и `std::get` не решают задачу? Пример:

```
template <size_t I, class TupleT> class WrapperT 
{ 
    using Element = typename std::tuple_element<I, TupleT>::type;
    Element mElement;

    public: WrapperT(const TupleT& tuple) 
        : mElement{std::get<I>(tuple)}
    {
    }
};
```